# The easiest way to iterate through a collection in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to be able to iterate through a collection so that I am able to go through all the objects. Here is my schema:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const moment = require('moment');

//Create user schema 
const UserSchema = new Schema ({
    username: { type: String, unique:true },
    password: {type:String},
    phonenumber: Number,
});

//**************PASSWORD STUFF *******************************
//Hash the password so it becomes encrypted.
UserSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password){
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password,bcrypt.genSaltSync(9));
}

UserSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password){
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password,this.password);
}
//************************************************************

//Schema model.
const User = mongoose.model('user-dodger', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's say you are trying to query all the users in your database, you can simply use js [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) function to do the job for you

Here is an example of what I'm saying

```
const queryAllUsers = () => {
    //Where User is you mongoose user model
    User.find({} , (err, users) => {
        if(err) //do something...

        users.map(user => {
            //Do somethign with the user
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use it right now and I can get into the User.find method but it doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 15):

Mongoose now has [async iterators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/querycursor.html#query_Query-Symbol.asyncIterator).  These have the advantage of not needing to load all documents in a collection before they start iterating:

```js
for await (const doc of Model.find()) {
  doc.name = "..."
  await doc.save();
}
```

Here is a [great blog post](https://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-mongoose-53-async-iterators.html) with more details.